# XGetAtomNames with XFree or XFreeStringList

Tags: c, x11

Hi there I am doing the following:

1. `XListProperties`
2. Allocate an array of pointers of length equal to number of atoms returned by 1
3. Pass the return value of 1 as second argument to `XGetAtomNames` and allocated array of 2 as last argument
4. Then I `XFree` the array from 2
5. `XFree` the return of 1

After awhile my app still crashes. Here is my code, it is js-ctypes, but i didnt tag it as such as they will not be able to help, this is an x11 question.

```
var numAtoms = ctypes.int();
var rez_ListProp = XListProperties(getDisplay(), XWindow, numAtoms.address());

if (rez_ListProp.isNull()) {
    // then probably failed
    throw new Error('XListProperties probably failed with BadWindow BUT is possible the window really has no properties set on it in which case i should not throw error on this line');
}

var atomsC = rez_ListProp;
var atomNames = ctypes.char.ptr.array(numAtoms)();
var rez_GetANames = XGetAtomNames(getDisplay(), atomsC, numAtoms, atomNames);

if (cutils.jscEqual(rez_GetANames, 0)) {
    throw new Error('failed XGetAtomNames');
}

for (var i = 0; i < atomNames.length; i++) {
    console.log('ATOM INFO - ', 'int:', atomsJS[i], 'atom name:', atomNames[i].readString());
    //XFree(atomNames[i]); // xfree here maybe is right thing to do
}

//XFreeStringList(atomNames);
XFree(atomNames);
XFree(rez_ListProp);
```

- Should I be doing `XFreeStringList` instead in place of step 4?

  - With this method i experience an almost immediate crash
- Or should I `XFree` each element in the array of step 2 after `XGetAtomNames`?

  - With this method I think its crash free

But i cant find any concrete writing (only my experimentations as proof) about this thats why i am asking.

Comment: @Lightness Added and also added code

Comment: Better, getting there, but still needs a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as you well know by now!